# Descargar diccionarios de webs y escribirlos en archivo JSON mediante bucle for

Tags: python, json, bucle-for, requests

Quiero descargar datos contenidos en una web a traves de una API REST. Dispongo de la URL y una serie de Pandas con las 4000 ID que van en la URL. La request me devuelve datos en forma de diccionario de cada peticion. Lo que necesito es que se cree un archivo JSON en el directorio señalado, y mediante un bucle for, que se repitan esas requests a la URL con cada ID diferente, y que se guarden en un mismo archivo JSON (que habria que crear inicialmente).

Este es mi codigo actualmente:

```
    def get_data():
        for id_num in df_data_info.index:
            data_info= requests.get(f"https://api.xz.org/3/data/{id_num} api_key=xa&en_US").json()
            with open("datas/backup/the_data.json", "w") as data_file:
                    json.dump(data_info, data_file)
        return print("Hecho!")
```

Ejecuto la funcion en Jupyter Notebook y... no hace nada. No aparece ningun error, simplemente no ocurre nada, no se crea el archivo, y no se suben los datos.

La parte del request funciona, ya que si introduzco manualmente un id_num en la variable data_info y return data_info, si que me da los datos para ese id_num concreto. Por lo que el error debe estar en la creacion del JSON, la escritura en el JSON o el bucle for, supongo...

Que falla?

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en el archivo que escribes,tienes que tener en cuenta que la ruta que defines tiene que estar ya creada por ejemplo si estas en colab prueba esto y verás que te funciona:

```
    def get_data():
    for id_num in df_data_info.index:
        data_info= requests.get(f"https://api.xz.org/3/data/{id_num} api_key=xa&en_US").json()
        with open("sample_data/the_data.json", "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(data_info, data_file)
    return print("Hecho!")
```

Con la libreria os tienes la funcion mkdir para crear directorios con python,ten claro que tienes que crear el directorio antes de escribir el archivo o asegurate que la ruta es correcta.
Un saludo y espero que te ayude.

Comment: Si ese fuera el caso, debería de dar un error, no fallar silenciosamente. Yo sospecho que, o no está llamando a la función, o todo está metido en un try-except que captura el error y cuando lo captura no hace nada. Igual cabe la posibilidad de que haya un comportamiento diferente en Colab que yo no sepa.

Comment: a ver viendo la función creo que esta deberia recibir un argumento con los ids,df_data_info.index como lo recoge la función?miraria esas cosas,a ver si te sirve de ayuda.